# Flush what's following \hfill to the next line if it doesn't fit

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm using `\hfill` to flush some text to the end of the line. However, when the stuff preceding `\hfill` takes up most of the line, the text at the end is broken over to the next line.

What I am want is this: When the stuff preceding `\hfill` doesn't leave enough space at the end of the line for the text following `\hfill`, that text should in its *entirety* flush to the *end* of the next line.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\hrule % show the margins
\rule{28em}{.2ex} \hfill S o m e t h i n g
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\foo{\hspace{\fill}\mbox{}\linebreak[0]\hspace*{\fill}}
\begin{document}

\hrule % show the margins

\bigskip

\rule{32em}{.2ex}\foo \mbox{S o m e t h i n g}

\bigskip

\rule{28em}{.2ex}\foo \mbox{S o m e t h i n g}

\bigskip

\rule{21em}{.2ex}\foo \mbox{S o m e t h i n g}

\bigskip

\rule{12em}{.2ex}\foo \mbox{S o m e t h i n g}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you might want to point out that it's necessary that the paragraph end (with either a blank line or `\par`) for that material to be flush right.

Comment: No idea what you did there, but works like a charm.

Comment: @David 
Is there any way to know that the \mbox{Something} will be put in the next line or at the end of the line without any `linebreak`?

You know, In my case I want to put some negative vertical space for the next line if `\linebreak` happens.

Comment: @javadr it's better to as a new question than comment on really old ones but probably the answer is no (but you can set `\baselineskip` to adjust the space of the stuff after the break. But ask a new question with a complete example showing the issue and someone will answer.