# Remove vertical space in examples (Linguex)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, linguex

I use the `linguex` package for numbering my examples. After each example I want there to be a reference, right aligned on the next line. This is my code

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 12 pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command. This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command   \begin{flushright}(Reference 2014)\end{flushright}

\ex. This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command \begin{flushright}(Reference 2014b)\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the reference between the examples comes with an equal distance to the preceding and the following example. I want the reference to follow the example with not extra vertical space, so that the only added space is between the examples.

I have tried using `\raggedright` instead of `flushright`, but the problem persists.

Best, Christine

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `\ex. `This is bla bla bla `\\\raggedleft`(Reference 2014)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding some negative vertical space inside the `flushright` environment should solve the problem.

Something like:

```
\begin{flushright}\vspace*{-.65\baselineskip}(Reference 2014)\end{flushright}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 12 pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command 
This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command 
This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command 
\begin{flushright}\vspace*{-.65\baselineskip}(Reference 2014)\end{flushright}

\ex. This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command 
This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command 
This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command 
\begin{flushright}\vspace*{-.65\baselineskip}(Reference 2014b)\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

By the way, the "command-form" of `flushright` is `\raggedleft` and not `\raggedright`.

---

### EDIT

The best thing should be to define a new command, let's say `\flushfill`, that is able to fill the line when there is enough room otherwise it has to flush the text right in the following line.

Following a trick described in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114077/27635) of David Carlisle, we can define:

```
\newcommand{\flushfill}[1]{\hspace{\fill}\mbox{}\linebreak[0]\hspace*{\fill}\mbox{#1}}
```

and use it as follows:

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 12 pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{linguex}

\newcommand{\flushfill}[1]{\hspace{\fill}\mbox{}\linebreak[0]\hspace*{\fill}\mbox{#1}}

\begin{document} 

\ex. This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command
This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command
This is an example that is too long 
\flushfill{(Reference 2014)}

\ex. This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command
This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command
This is an example that is too long for me to use the
\flushfill{(Reference 2014a)}

\ex. This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command
This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command
This is an example that is too long for me to use the hfill-command
\flushfill{(Reference 2014b)}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! These are very useful tips! 

I couldn't get \flushfill to be right aligned on the next page when the "references" were too long. Any idea as to why? I just copied the code above.

Comment: @Christine "references" cannot be longer than a line since they are inside a box... Anyway, if the answer solves your problem, consider accepting it. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)