# Problem with flushing mbox to the next line if it doesn't fit

Tags: horizontal-alignment, fill

I try to use the command outlined by David Carlisle here:
[Flush what's following \hfill to the next line if it doesn't fit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114069/flush-whats-following-hfill-to-the-next-line-if-it-doesnt-fit/114077#114077)

But in this MWE it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage[textwidth=10cm]{geometry}

\def\foo{\hspace{\fill}\mbox{}\linebreak[0]\hspace*{\fill}}

\begin{document}
Schöne Verhältnis herzustellen, in
               welchem sich erst das eigentliche Talent zeigt, bleibt abzuwarten.\foo\mbox{H. B.}      
\end{document}
```

The name of the author is moved to the next line even though there is enough space:
[image]

Why?

Comment: Seems to be caused by `babel`.  In particular, by the `ngerman` option.  Change `ngerman` to `english` to see the effect.

Comment: The posted code does not make the image shown (eg the accented letters fail as inputenc isn't used), and HB comes on line 2.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes the difference is that german adds a hyphen on the first line and there is a relatively high cost to a paragraph with a hyphen on the penultimate line.

Comment: @david-carlisle you're right, I use xelatex and there the output is as described. but i'll check the proposed solutions now.

Comment: If you use xelatex you really should not be using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try a bit harder to discourage a line break at that point:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage[textwidth=10cm]{geometry}

\def\foo{\hspace{\fill}\mbox{}\nolinebreak[3]\hspace*{\fill}}

\begin{document}
Schöne Verhältnis herzustellen, in
               welchem sich erst das eigentliche Talent zeigt, bleibt abzuwarten.\foo\mbox{H. B.}      
\end{document}
```

The reason TeX is taking three lines is because it penalises a hyphen on the penultimate line.  If you leave the linebreak penalty as 0 but lower the final hyphen demerit to 50 by adding

```
\finalhyphendemerits=50
```

it also just takes two lines.

Comment: Can you comment on `\linebreak[0]` versus `\nolinebreak[3]`?  What is going on inside TeX at that point?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I was adding more text as you were commenting

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the hyphenation in the previous line. LaTeX tries normally to avoid that there is hyphenation is the line before the last. The penalty for this is `\finalhyphendemerits`. That's why the code from the TeX-Book (see link below) sets it locally to 0 (and also \parfillskip to 0). If you set it too zero it compiles as expected:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage[textwidth=10cm]{geometry}

\def\foo{\hspace{\fill}\mbox{}\linebreak[0]\hspace*{\fill}}

\begin{document}\finalhyphendemerits=0

Schöne Verhältnis herzustellen, in
               welchem sich erst das eigentliche Talent zeigt, bleibt abzuwarten.\foo\mbox{H. B.}
\end{document}
```

For a safer implementation see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16333/2388.

Comment: it works! I'll try the safer implementation right away. but would a general approach work as well: \def\foo{\finalhyphendemerits=0\hspace{\fill}\mbox{}\linebreak[0]\hspace*{\fill}} also work or would that produce another problem?

Comment: @MartinMueller there is no grouping so that would set the demerits for the rest of the document unless the paragraph was in some other group

Comment: You are changing `\finalhyphendemerits` globally, so it will affect following paragraphs.