# TeXbook example: Put something flush right on line if it fits, on next line otherwise

Tags: horizontal-alignment, texbook.tex

I am certain I remember an example from the TeXbook where Knuth showed how to put something (I think it was the name of the author of a quote in the example) flush right on the last line of a paragraph if it fits, or flush right on the next line if it doesn't. (Very much like the LaTeX version in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114077/48973).) However I can't seem to find it anymore.

Where in the TeXbook is this example? Or am I crazy and it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the index for “Bourbaki”

```
Bourbaki, Nicolas, 106.
```

On page 106 you find

```
\def\signed #1 (#2){{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
  \hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil\sl#1\/ \rm(#2)
  \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}}
```

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91564/4427