How can change the spacing of text while using multicols and enumerate environments?
I want the text 'rights' to be on the same line of the text 'One who defends his country`s freedom or'.
The code I've used is :
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=15mm,vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\vspace{3mm}
\textbf{V.} \textbf{Write the correct one word substitutions for the following.} 
\hfill \textbf{(4)} \\
\end{flushleft}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[nosep,left=0pt,label=\arabic*),itemsep=10pt]
\item Begin all powerful
\item A person who eats too much.
\item A place where a person lives permanently.
\item One who defends his country`s freedom or rights.   
\begin{itemize}[nosep,left=3cm,label= ,itemsep=10pt]
\item  \rule{4cm}{0.75pt}
\item  \rule{4cm}{0.75pt}
\item  \rule{4cm}{0.75pt} 
\item  \rule{4cm}{0.75pt} 
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}       
\end{multicols}
\end{document}

The output that I get when I run this code is :

The output that I'm looking for is something like this :


And once again saying a big thank you to everyone who helped me in my last post.

Do I understand correctly that you want the left column to be wider than the right column?

I get the impression that you actually want the left column to be wider than the right column with the horizontal lines. Columns of different widths are not supported by multicol. In addition, your use of multicol results in the problem that in the case of a page break within the construct, the lines are no longer necessarily next to the texts.
A possible solution for both problems would be to use two minipage environments. In this case, however, a page break within the construct is completely prevented.
Assuming that page breaks should be possible and that the line for multi-line items should always be at the height of the first line, it would be possible to set the line out of the label and increase the right margin of the enumeration. This could look like this, for example:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=15mm,vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand*\itemruleright[1][0pt]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \makebox[\dimeval{\linewidth+\rightmargin+#1}][r]{\rule{4cm}{.75pt}}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\Roman{subsubsection}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{subsubsection}{4}% for demonstration only

Note: I'm using real headings, because I don't like manual numbering and there

\subsubsection{Write the correct one word substitutions for the following. 
\hfill \textbf{(4)}}

\begin{enumerate}[nosep,left=0pt,label={\itemruleright[-.5cm]\arabic*)},itemsep=10pt,rightmargin=5.5cm]
\item Begin all powerful
\item A person who eats too much.
\item A place where a person lives permanently.
\item One who defends his country`s freedom or rights.
\item And one more item that really does not fit into a single line of the enumeration.
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip

\Blindtext[3]

\subsubsection{Write the correct one word substitutions for the following
  and note that the label hack works even with page breaks inside the
  enumeration list.\hfill \textbf{(4)}}

\begin{enumerate}[nosep,left=0pt,label={\itemruleright[-.5cm]\arabic*)},itemsep=10pt,rightmargin=5.5cm]
\item Begin all powerful
\item A person who eats too much.
\item A place where a person lives permanently.
\item One who defends his country`s freedom or rights.
\item And one more item that really does not fit into a single line of the enumeration.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


Instead of using \subsubsection you could also define a new section like command. There are classes like the KOMA-Script classes and package like titlesec that support definition of extra sectioning commands.
The optional argument of \itemruleright in the example above is used to optionally move the lines to the right (positive length) or left (negative length).
Remark: The \makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[…][r]{…}} trick is the same, I've shown and explained here.
It should also be noted that several packages already exist for creating exercises and creating exams and the like.

You should better organize your typescript, to begin with.
Add a zero space box…
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=15mm,vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{question}
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\Roman{question}}

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621309/4427
\newenvironment{question}[2]{% #1 = points, #2 = question text
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \stepcounter{question}%
  \noindent{\bfseries \thequestion. #2{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
  \hspace{2em}\mbox{}\nobreak\hfil(#1)\parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}}%
  \vspace{\topsep}
}{\par\addvspace{\topsep}}

\newenvironment{fillitems}{%
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep,left=0pt,label=\arabic*),itemsep=10pt,rightmargin=4.5cm]%
}{\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\fitem}{%
  \item
  \makebox[0pt][l]{% this is zero space
    \makebox[\dimeval{\linewidth+\rightmargin}][r]{% this is the full line width
      \rule{4cm}{0.75pt}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{question}{4} % pretend that the next question is number 5

\begin{question}{4}{Write the correct one word substitutions for the following.}
\begin{fillitems}
\fitem Begin all powerful
\fitem A person who eats too much.
\fitem A place where a person lives permanently.
\fitem One who defends his country`s freedom or rights.   
\fitem 'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
       Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
       All mimsy were the borogoves,
       And the mome raths outgrabe.
\end{fillitems}
\end{question}

\begin{question}{4}{Write the correct one word substitutions for the following; beware
that this text is uselessly longer.}
\begin{fillitems}
\fitem Begin all powerful
\fitem A person who eats too much.
\fitem A place where a person lives permanently.
\fitem One who defends his country`s freedom or rights.   
\fitem 'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
       Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
       All mimsy were the borogoves,
       And the mome raths outgrabe.
\end{fillitems}
\end{question}

\end{document}


